# Asking loopback to igone id param while creating in mongodb connector

Tags: mongodb, loopbackjs

Please excuse me this newbie question ....

If during creation POST, if the user sends an id as part of the param  how do i inform the connector to ignore it.

I have follow json config for the model ...

```
{
  "name": "Activity",
  "plural": "activities",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "action"             : { "type" : "string" },
    "status"             : { "type" : "date" },
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

I was expecting mongodb connector to know that I want it it to create an ID because I have following param

```
idInjection": true,
```

For some reason when "id" param is send with the call, the connector does not create a record new ObjectId  instead tries to created an record with send id

I suspect I am doing something wrong, bu fail to find in the documentation to rectify this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/), under **_id Field**. If you send an "_id" field, MongoDB doesn't create it.

NB. MongoDB only cares about "`_id`" field, not "`id`" fields, so I'm guessing you have a type there, or have somehow changed this special name in the configuration.

Comment: Thank you for taking look at this. Loopback mongodb connector documentation mentions that_id is exposed as id so I assume setting "idInjection": true" should create record ignoring id during record creation

Comment: Do you have an example of a document that has then both an "_id" and an "id"? A document in MongoDB **always** has an ObjectId.